# Error in renderDataTable

Tags: r, shiny

When I'm trying to run this code as a Shiny app in R, I'm facing this error:

> Error in renderDataTable({ : unused argument (rownames = FALSE)

```
output$table <- renderDataTable({

if(is.null(fdata()))
{return ()}

if(input$flevel=="Weekly")
{
  if(input$flevel2=="Store")
  {
    data<-fdata()
    data <- data[data$SKU == input$xcol,]
    data <- data[data$Store == input$ycol,]
    data
  }
  else if(input$flevel2=="Region")
  {
    data<-fdata()
    data <- data[data$SKU == input$xcol,]
    data <- data[data$Region == input$ycol,]
    # data <- aggregate(Sales~Date+SKU+Region_Name,data = data,FUN = sum,na.rm=TRUE)
    data
  }
}
else if(input$flevel=="Monthly")
{
  if(input$flevel2=="Store")
  {
    dmsales<-MonthManp()
    data<-dmsales[[4]]
    data <- data[data$SKU == input$xcol,]
    data <- data[data$Store == input$ycol,]
    data
  }
  else if(input$flevel2=="Region")
  {
    dmsales<-MonthManp()
    data<-dmsales[[4]]
    data <- data[data$SKU == input$xcol,]
    data <- data[data$Region == input$ycol,]
    data
    # data <- aggregate(Sales~Date+product_id+loc_id+Channel_Name,data = data,FUN = sum,na.rm=TRUE)
  }
} }, options = list(searching = FALSE),rownames=FALSE)
```

All my brackets are properly closed and the rownames is inside the datatable not the options tab. Can anyone pls help me in this. I'm a newbie in Shiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params for 
[renderDataTable](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderDataTable.html) are:

```
renderDataTable(expr, options = NULL, searchDelay = 500,
  callback = "function(oTable) {}", escape = TRUE, env = parent.frame(),
  quoted = FALSE, outputArgs = list())
```

You could use the following format:

```
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(df,options = list(searching=FALSE),rownames= FALSE)
  })
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Florian. I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, my issue got resolved. Thanks, Florian and sorry for not replying earlier. I had completely forgotten about this.

Comment: Thanks again Cheers.